# Javascript Closure "creating Local variable for the callback function"

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript DatPicker like

```
datefield = $('fromdate');

datepicker = new DatePicker(wrapper, 
   {months:1
   , onSelect: function(datefield) {
                 return function() {
                   onDatePick();
                 } 
               }( datefield ) 
    });
```

where `onSelect` is a callback function which will be called when the user clicks on a Date. and DatePicker passed the Selected  Date as Callback function's argument. This Date will be written in the `datefield` input field.

I thought that within the closoure this field will be avialble as local variable, but it is always undefined.

Comment: Shouldn't you pass it on as a parameter like `onDatePick( datefield );` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to add parameter to callback function, you need to do something like this:

```
datefield = $('fromdate');
datepicker = new DatePicker(wrapper, 
   {months:1
   , onSelect: (function(datefield) {
                 return function() {
                   onDatePick();
                 } 
               }) (datefield) 
    });
```